# Calling Window_Loaded event from an another class

Tags: c#, sql, wpf, datagrid

My MainWindow.xaml.cs class includes following `Window_Loaded` Event:

```
public void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    SQLClass sqlclass = new SQLClass();
    sqlclass.initSQL(dataGrid1);
}
```

So I'm calling this `initSql(Datagrid dataGrid)` method from the `SQLClass`, which actually binds my dataGrid to the Sql table.

```
public void initSQL(DataGrid dataGrid)
{
    AppDomain.CurrentDomain.SetData("DataDirectory", "C:\\Users\\Osman\\");
    try
    {
        using (SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection("Data Source=.\\SQLExpress;Initial Catalog=FinalApplication1;Integrated Security=True;"))
        {

            cn.Open();
            SqlDataAdapter adap = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT Time, Condition FROM Status", cn);
            System.Data.DataSet ds = new System.Data.DataSet();
            adap.Fill(ds, "Status");
            dataGrid.DataContext = ds.Tables["Status"].DefaultView;
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Error\n" + ex.Message, "Error", MessageBoxButton.OK, MessageBoxImage.Error);
    }
}
```

This works perfectly on a startup, but when I want to update the dataGrid after inserting a value to the Sql table, I'm then calling the `Window_Loaded` method from from my `BluetoothLE` class:

```
public class BluetoothLE
{
    private void dispatcherTimer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        dispatcherTimer.Stop();
        MainWindow mainwin = new MainWindow();
        mainwin.Window_Loaded(this, null);
    }
}
```

The issue is that the dataGrid does not update in this case. The `Window_Loaded` method is triggered, but it does not update the dataGrid. What's actually wrong here ?.

Comment: First, name your method something decent, instead of `..._Loaded`. Split the actual call into a separate method. Second, any exception thrown? Seems like a possible cross-thread operation to me.

Answer (score 1):

your are creating a new instance of your main window where you don't show rather than updating `datagrid` of your current `MainWindow`. Try:

```
private void Update()
{
    //enter datagrid functionality you have in window load event
}

public class BluetoothLE
{
    private void dispatcherTimer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        dispatcherTimer.Stop();
        Update();
    }
}
```

Comment: I have tried this but it does not make any difference

Answer (score 1):

The code:

```
MainWindow mainwin = new MainWindow();
mainwin.Window_Loaded(this, null);
```

will not work, you need to call `Window_Loaded` on the current instance of `MainWindow`, creating a new instance (with the `new MainWindow()` line) won't affect the window that's displayed on the screen.

I don't know where you create your `BluetoothLE` class but it needs to have a reference to the `MainWindow` instance so it can call methods on it. Something like the following:

```
public class BluetoothLE
{
    private MainWindow windowInstance;
    public BluetoothLE(MainWindow windowInstance) {
        this.windowInstance = windowInstance;
    }
    private void dispatcherTimer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        dispatcherTimer.Stop();
        windowInstance.Window_Loaded(this, null);
    }
}
```

And if you create `BluetoothLE` from *inside* `MainWindow`:

```
var bluetooth = new BluetoothLE(this);
```

If you wanted to get rid of that dependence (you probably should in the long run) you might want to use C# events, but that's another story.

Also pull out your update code into a separate method called `UpdateGrid()` or something and call it from the `Window_Load` event and other places you need to update, `Window_Load` shouldn't be used to update the UI from elsewhere.

Comment: The windowInstance.Window_Loaded(this, null) returns a NullReferenceException.

It says that the object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Comment: Are you creating your `BlutoothLE` instance with `var bluetooth = new BluetoothLE(this);`?

Comment: No, I'm not creating BluetoothLE inside MainWindow. It is a separate class.

Answer (score 0):

```
((MainWindow)Application.Current.MainWindow).Window_Loaded(this, null);
```

This should do what you are looking to do, though it's all a pretty ugly way of doing it.